# LINQ - Left join and Group by and Sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two lists

```
var stores = new[] 
{
    new { Code = 1, Name = "Store 1" },
    new { Code = 2, Name = "Store 2" }    
};

var orders = new[] 
{
    new { Code = 1, StoreCode = 1, TotalValue = 14.12 },
    new { Code = 2, StoreCode = 1, TotalValue = 24.12 }
};
```

OUTPUT

StoreName = Store 1 | TotalValue = 38.24

StoreName = Store 2 | TotalValue = 0

How can I translate this into LINQ to SQL?

```
var lj = (from s in stores
          join o in orders on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into joined
          from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
          group s by new
          {
              StoreCode = s.Code,
              StoreName = s.Name
          }
              into grp
              select new
              {
                  StoreName = grp.Key.StoreName,
                  TotalValue = ???
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you doing group join, all orders related to store will be in group, and you will have access to store object. So, simply use `s.Name` to get name of store, and `g.Sum()` to calculate total of orders:

```
var lj = (from s in db.stores
          join o in db.orders on s.Code equals o.StoreCode into g
          select new {
             StoreCode = s.Name,
             TotalValue = g.Sum(x => x.TotalValue)
          }).ToList();
```

Note - from your sample it looks like you don't need to group by store name and code, because code looks like primary key and it's unlikely you will have several stores with same primary key but different names.

Comment: could you translate using lambda?